# How do I change the status of the inputswitch in the form, depending upon the data from backend?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Hi I am new to angular and I am using ***primeNg*** components in which I have a form and in my form I have a `<p-inputswitch>` tag and I have my ***JSON*** data coming from the backend and each record has

`{...`

`"status": "ACTIVE"`

`....},`

either the status is active or inactive. I want this ***inputSwitch*** to be in ON position if the status is Active else keep it in Off Position.
[This is what my input switch looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfnO2.png)

Also to mention - I have many no: of records which have status active or inactive.

This is my input formcontrolName

```
<div class="col-12">
    <p-inputSwitch onLabel="Active" offLabel="Inactive" formControlName="status" ></p-inputSwitch>                                          
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init the form via reactive forms (guess so since you are using formControlName).

your.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <p-inputSwitch formControlName="status"></p-inputSwitch>
</form>
<div>
  {{ form.value | json }}
</div>
<button
  (click)="getBackendData()"
  pButton
  pRipple
  type="button"
  label="Get Backend Data"
  class="p-button-raised"
></button>
```

your.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export interface BackendData {
  status: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  mockedBackendData: BackendData = {
    status: 'ACTIVE',
  };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      status: [false],
    });
  }

  // Only for demonstration purpose
  // Try to never use setTimeout
  // here you put ur async side effect
  // retrieving the data from the backend
  getBackendData() {
    this.mockedBackendData.status =
      this.mockedBackendData.status === 'ACTIVE' ? 'INACTIVE' : 'ACTIVE';

    this.form.patchValue({
      switch: this.mockedBackendData.status === 'ACTIVE' ? false : true,
    });
  }
}
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputswitch-demo-fwbdox?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hi sagat, thanks for the answer, I also wanted to mention, my form is an edit form , where in I have to show the values, and if from the backend"status":"ACTIVE" then the switch should change to (true) value. and also while patching value, I want to check whether the status:"ACTIVE" or not, then only I will be able to put the (true) or (false)

Comment: I dont get what exactly u mean. The way I showed you should be enough to do everything you wanted to. When the data from backend p0asses you a true and u patch the value on the form input it goes to true if u patch value false it is not going to switch to true.

Comment: I updated the Stackblitz, it would be nice if the answer helped you to upvote and mark as correct answer. regards

Comment: Yes I think its okay now

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using ReactiveForms, here's a good way to do it:
component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.scss']
})
export class Component implements OnInit {
  public status: FormControl = new FormControl(false);
  public formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    status: this.status
  });
  
  public constructor(private service: Service) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getStatus$().subscribe(status => {
      this.status.setValue(status);
      this.status.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
}
```